# Conditionally changing cell value when string appears in a separate column in R: time series

Tags: r

Problem:

The starting states of "b" and "c" are determined by presence in another table.

```
dd$b[1] <- ifelse( "b" %in% table,1,0)  
dd$c[1] <- ifelse( "c" %in% table,1,0)
```

I'm hoping to come up with a formula that:

1. Checks to see if the value in `column a` contains "lamp" and "b" and makes `b` a 0 if so,
2. Else checks to see if the value in `column a` contains "lion" and "b" and makes `b` a 1 if so,
3. Or defaults to the value in the previous row for `b`.

To include to example outputs, the column c is included and should follow the same rules as the above.

Referring to the cell value above is crucial as a third step, because this is designed "change states" as time progresses.

Pasteable table:

```
dd = read.table(header = T, text = "    time   a    b   c   d   s   
k   w
1   18:41  'b d cat'       1     0   1   0    0   1
2   18:43  'b d dog'       1     0   1   0    0   1
3   18:47  'b d lamp'      0     0   0   0    0   1
4   18:51  'b s dog'       0     0   0   0    0   1
5   18:52  'b k cat'       0     0   0   0    0   1
6   18:57  'b c lion'      1     1   0   0    0   1
7   18:59  'b a dog'       1     1   0   0    0   1
8   19:23  'b w lamp'      0     1   0   0    0   0 
9   19:25  'b r cat'       0     1   0   0    0   0")
```

Desired Output:

```
    time   a           b      c
1   18:41  b d cat       1     0
2   18:43  b d dog       1     0 
3   18:47  b d lamp      0     0
4   18:51  b s dog       0     0
5   18:52  b k cat       0     0
6   18:57  b c lion      1     1
7   18:59  b a dog       1     1
8   19:23  b w lamp      0     1 
9   19:25  b r cat       0     1
```

Essentially, I am looking for a way to make column a's values operate as an on/off switch for the flag variables in b and c.

This is something that can be done quickly in Excel using relational formulas, but I would love an elegant R-based solution if one exists!

To solve the problem, the tricks I would need to incorporate (at least to my understanding) would be

1. Come up with a formula and have it only apply to all rows **except** the first row.
2. Refer to the row above if states are not changed based on the first two bits of logic.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show the expected output

Comment: While there are other ways to do this I would take a look at `?grepl`. `df$b[grepl("lamp", df$a)] <- 0`

Comment: Hi @akrun.  I should have been more clear that the table I had included was the desired output.  I've edited the question based on your input.

Comment: @Ian Wesley Thank you for the direction.  I think grepl may be the part of the cure.  The references to another table for the top row and the references to the cell above have got me stuck.

Comment: @Pake sorry I am having a very hard time understanding what you are trying to accomplish.  Also it sounds like there is probably a better data structure to use.  You seem to be approaching this as an Excel problem rather than as an R problem.  However look at `?dplyr::lag` to lag to another row.

Comment: Just fill in the results for conditions 1 and 2 using `grepl`, leaving everything else as `NA`. Then use `zoo::na.locf` to fill all the `NA`s with the previous non-missing value.

Comment: I think Gregor's suggestion is the best way to go, but it'd be easier to illustrate the details it if your example was easily reproducible (eg, by copy-paste into an r console). For guidance, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading in your data and setting all but the 1st row of columns `b` and `c` to `NA`:

```
dd = read.table(header = T, text = "    time   a           b      c
1   18:41  'b d cat'       1     0
2   18:43  'b d dog'       1     0 
3   18:47  'b d lamp'      0     0
4   18:51  'b s dog'       0     0
5   18:52  'b k cat'       0     0
6   18:57  'b c lion'      1     1
7   18:59  'b a dog'       1     1
8   19:23  'b w lamp'      0     1 
9   19:25  'b r cat'       0     1")

dd$b[-1] = NA
dd$c[-1] = NA

dd
#    time        a  b  c
# 1 18:41  b d cat  1  0
# 2 18:43  b d dog NA NA
# 3 18:47 b d lamp NA NA
# 4 18:51  b s dog NA NA
# 5 18:52  b k cat NA NA
# 6 18:57 b c lion NA NA
# 7 18:59  b a dog NA NA
# 8 19:23 b w lamp NA NA
# 9 19:25  b r cat NA NA
```

I think the above is the starting point (in the future it would be nice if you provide a copy/pasteable starting point as above).

We'll create a new column `on_off` that holds the shared logic looking for `lamp` and `lion`:

```
dd$on_off = NA
dd$on_off[c(FALSE, grepl(pattern = "lamp", x = dd$a[-1]))] = 0
dd$on_off[c(FALSE, grepl(pattern = "lion", x = dd$a[-1]))] = 1
```

Then we'll reference that column while searching the string for `b` or `c` by itself (`"\\b"` is a regex pattern for a word boundary, this keeps us from matching, e.g., the `"c"` in `"cat"`):

```
dd$b[-1] = ifelse(grepl("\\bb\\b", dd$a[-1]), dd$on_off[-1], NA)
dd$c[-1] = ifelse(grepl("\\bc\\b", dd$a[-1]), dd$on_off[-1], NA)
```

Lastly, we fill in the missing values with the previous observation:

```
dd$b = zoo::na.locf(dd$b)
dd$c = zoo::na.locf(dd$c)

dd
#    time        a b c on_off
# 1 18:41  b d cat 1 0     NA
# 2 18:43  b d dog 1 0     NA
# 3 18:47 b d lamp 0 0      0
# 4 18:51  b s dog 0 0     NA
# 5 18:52  b k cat 0 0     NA
# 6 18:57 b c lion 1 1      1
# 7 18:59  b a dog 1 1     NA
# 8 19:23 b w lamp 0 1      0
# 9 19:25  b r cat 0 1     NA
```

You can remove the `on_off` column with `dd$on_off = NULL`. I leave it in to make things a little clearer.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer!  I added a pasteable table on your recommendation.  Would this code be easily scaled for multiple columns? Say, if there were dozens of columns beyond b and c?

Comment: We can scale fairly easily - it's nice to include that need in the original question as well. I'd recommend doing a simple for loop. Do `for (col in <column names to loop over>)` and replace the `dd$b` with `dd[[col]]` and the `grepl` pattern with `paste0("\\b", col, "\\b")`. I'm at work now, but this evening if you still need help I can work an example.